# Accessing variable stored in class from another file

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to access the $new_id variable in the method below (from public class youth_teams) from an outside file but I can't figure out how. I have it printing the lastInsertID correctly from inside the file which contains the method but would like to be able to access the variable in other files also.

```
public function addTeam(
    $team_name,
    &$error
) {
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `' . $this->table . '` (
    `team_name`
) VALUES (
    :team_name
)');
    $query->bindParam(':team_name', $team_name);
    $query->execute();

    print_r($query->errorInfo());
    print $this->pdo->lastInsertID();
    $new_id = $this->pdo->lastInsertID();
    return $new_id;                             
}
```

Here's the code I've tried from the OTHER FILE:

```
sw::shared()->youth_teams->addTeam (
    $team_name,
    $error
);  

$temp_two = sw::shared()->youth_teams->addTeam->pdo->lastInsertID();
echo "new id: " . $temp_two . "<br>";
```

Of course that is not working... What's the correct path to access $new_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$temp_two = sw::shared()->youth_teams->addTeam($team, $error);
```

`addTeam()` is a function that returns `$new_id`, so you need to call it with `()`.

If you really want to be able to access `$new_id` directly, you can declare it global:

```
public function addTeam(
    $team_name,
    &$error
) {
    global $new_id;
    ...
```

Comment: he should also specify parameters of this function

Comment: is there a way to pull out just the $new_id value though?

Comment: I updated my original code to show the flow. After the addTeam() method runs I want to be able to get the $new_id value out and then use it to run another method

Comment: Your update doesn't make sense. Why are you doing the same thing twice? The second one tries to use `addTeam` as a property instead of a function, but that's not what it is.

Comment: What do you mean by `use it to run another method`? `$new_id` is just an ID number from the database, it's not a PHP object.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make sense. Here's what I ended up doing in the outside file... $temp_two = sw::shared()->pdo->lastInsertId(); echo "new id: " . $temp_two . "<br>";

Comment: I don't understand why you're not just using the return value of `addTeam()`, isn't that what it's for? You asked how to do it, I showed you, but you don't want to do it the right way.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I just don't necessarily understand everything you're saying. I am not as skilled as you.

Comment: It's really beginner stuff. The function returns a value. If you want to use that value, you assign the function result to a variable. I don't know how to explain it any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong with this?

```
$sw = new sw();

$temp_two = $sw->addTeam( $team, $error );

echo "new id: " . $temp_two . "<br>";
```

If you can call `sw::shared()` from the outside file, you can assign the object.

I probably am not fully understanding your code, if not, please fully explain the following:

```
sw::shared()->youth_teams->addTeam( $team, $error );

// 1. What does the shared() method do?
// 2. What is the youth_teams property?
```

If it's needed, might I suggest adding the assignment directly into the `addTeam()` function and use the above format to return the id only.